# R function to encapsulate traverse plus emit value

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I am looking for an R function to traverse an array and emit indices for the elements which pass a test. I'm thinking it will have the same effect as this bit of Python code:

```
>>> y = (12, 44, 8, -2, 5)
>>> [i for i in range(5) if y[i] < 10]
[2, 3, 4]
```

I can think of ways to accomplish this via `sapply` and subset indexing, for example:

```
> c(12, 44, 8, -2, 5) -> y
> sapply (1:5, function (i) y[[i]] < 10) -> ii
> which(ii)
[1] 3 4 5
```

but I am wondering if there is a ready-made function, in base R or any library, for it. I've skimmed the documentation for purrr and I don't see it there, although I could easily have overlooked it.

Aside from hoping to find something elegant, I think I'd like to avoid constructing the intermediate array `ii` since it's going to be very large (actually the Cartesian product of two arrays) and the number of positive cases is much smaller. A nonfunctional way to accomplish that would be to traverse the array and `prepend` or otherwise push positive cases onto a result array.

Comment: Are you looking for `which(y < 10)`?

Comment: I suspect you may have created an over-simplified example. In R, the key question for efficiency will always be *"can it be vectorized?"* In this case, `<` is already vectorized, so the `sapply` call is inefficient. As Martin says, `which(y < 10)` is nice and simple. If your test is more complex, you may need to bring your example closer in complexity to the real problem.

Comment: As an aside, `[[` are needed for lists, but your `y` is a plain old vector, so the `[[` look strange. `[` will suffice.

Comment: I'd note, also, that if your `i` might be more complicated than `1:5`, say `i = c(2, 4, 5)`, you can still be elegant and efficient with `i[y[i] < 10]`. No need for `sapply` or anything.